# A good way to take network requests out of Application object?

Tags: android, performance, android-activity

In [the wonderful article](https://medium.com/google-developers/developing-for-android-iii-2efc140167fd) by Chet Haase I read this advice which I find quite important:

> never make a network request in your Application object. That object
>   may be created when one of the app’s Services or BroadcastReceivers is
>   started; hitting the network will turn code that does a local update
>   at a specific frequency into a regular DDoS.

The application I work on currently follows this (bad) practise: it performs a user login in `Application.onCreate()` - on a background thread of course, but still. This is a requirement: user needs to be logged in before any activity would do any other tasks, which usually depend on logged in user. I currently do this using RxJava in a way that any activity task observables are flatMapped onto an userlogin event and it works quite nice.

So if I should take that login task out of `Application`, where should it go? At first I thought it would be nice to use `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` and watch for the first activity to be created. But this callback (`onActivityCreated`) will be called after creation, which is too late for me.

So I think that this should be done by creating some `BaseActivity` class and putting login and other initialization calls in it's first `onCreate()`. But I don't feel this is too good, because I'm mixing some app-wide logic in an activity class, it's smelly...

Anything I could have missed?

Answer (score 1):

**SplashActivity**

An activity that starts the application. It checks for resources availability and if needed, obtains them. It also checks whether there is an active user session, and if there isn't performs a log in, if there are remembered credentials, or redirects the user to the Login/Register screen

**BaseActivity**

An activity that is specific for your app and that holds initialization and lifecycle callback code that is applicable for all your activities in the application.

Comment: So this way I end up with 2 activities on start? SplashActivity and then MainActivity. I guess I can disable transition animations and this would look like one activity

Comment: If the only thing you're gonna do in SplashActivity is to check for user session, then there is no point in using a SplashActivity, but do this in your MainActivity (or BaseActivity MainActivity extends from) onResume. SplashActivity is used if you have long running (1-5 seconds) operations that obtain and create resources (files, bitmaps etc) and you want to show a loader or a loading image.

Comment: The thing is that app can have several activities and Android can restore app from recents by launching **any** activity, not only the MainActivity. And in each case I need to log a user in on start. So the only good place seems to be the BaseActivity, but this is the conclusion I came to too, and I wonder if this is the only one. Doesn't feel to good (see question)

Comment: It is perfectly normal to include app-wide logic in a Base Activity that all activities (which the app consists of) extend from

Comment: well, I am not sure I agree fully. BaseActivity is for Activity stuff, UI stuff, not app initialization stuff. So I agree that this seems like a way to do this, but I do not like it. Will wait a bit more, maybe some other solution pops up.

Comment: okay I am interested in alternatives, too. I disagree that this is app initialization stuff, because log in operation may be user-invoked by a user interface (at least that's how it works in most applications), not only an automatic operation

Comment: also, Activity is the main application component that takes care of user interaction with the app, namely - app brought to front or minimized

Comment: You can also delegate the login logic to a service, but again, it needs to be started at a certain time in the app's lifecycle, which you get callbacks for in the Activity